# Separating an object with boolean intersection modifier generates extra vertices

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes, boolean-modifier

I have a large model (*.obj format) that I want to split into cubes. I am doing this by creating an array of cubes and then applying a boolean modifier to the model, using the cube array as the operand object.

[image: Model with cube array]

The problem I am having is that some vertices of the initial model get connected to the cubes in the array.

[image: Model vertices connected to the cubes of the array]

Once I've applied the boolean modifier and separate the mesh by loose parts I get a mesh which incorporates some of the cubes of the initial array.

[image: Final separated model]

How can I stop this from happening? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you have to check the "hole tolerant" option in the boolean modifier, because your mesh is not an enclosed mesh, so technically it has a 'hole'.

Comment: If it doesn't work you can also add a bit of thickness to your base mesh with a solidify modifier, set the material offset to 1 and add two materials to the object. Apply the solidify and the boolean, then in edit mode select the second material faces and delete them, including their vertices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't ask for a solution for *Geometry Nodes*, but I would suggest you to solve your task with it.

It's simpler than it looks at first glance, but this setup should do exactly what you want it to do:

[image]

Simply put, here I create a mesh from a grid that is used to slice up the terrain, and has the following advantages:

- There are no duplicate faces/edges as a result, as is the case with your example, and which would only cause unnecessary problems.
- You can basically cut any mesh you want.
- You can flexibly influence the subdivision on the X and Y axes via the modifier panel.
- The resulting connected faces (mesh islands) have their own index, and can be processed separately (for example in *Geometry Nodes*).

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly.