# Contour lines every z-level of this stepped landscape

Tags: geometry-nodes, procedural, select

[image]

Trying to recreate this holographic animation all by myself with geometry nodes. Watching several tutorials I used a texture map to create the landscape layout. I do not know how to get a selection of all the curve points on every z-level to create al line with those points. I need the points on the line afterwards to have a pulsading sphere go around a random set of these lines.

[image]

[image]

Comment: No, you don't need the lines - you could do all this with shader nodes. But you still want a "just" geometry nodes solution? if yes, one way would be to use a dense grid and use raycast with a specific length and convert that to a curve

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add golden line to my maps?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/211883/how-to-add-golden-line-to-my-maps) Maybe the question shouldn't be closed or should be reopened when you clarify why the `geometry-nodes` tag.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I want a geonodes only solutions since I need a fully procedural setup for a sliding landscape video. The idea was to set the materials as a last step. I know about the shader setup. With both of your answers I will have a look at the raycast nodes and also see if some math (modular) node on the z-axis will create the same effect as the shader nodes. The golden line is a really nice one!

Comment: The raycast node is to calculate if rays are casted onto an object and then specify a method. I only have one object (a plane) that I edit, so I do not understand yet how I could use that specific geometry node. I'm now delving into how to get shader/material nodes in a geonodes setup. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/279201/how-to-cut-a-mesh-into-a-flexible-number-of-pieces-along-a-certain-axis/

Comment: Thanks. This does partly answer my question. It is exactly how it is done with the shader nodes on a material, but there is no solution to how use the points on the created contour lines. in order to let a pulsading sphere flow around it. Two days ago I also found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cvTiNFzhbcE) explanation that is more what I had in my mind. Now trying to find a solution to add the pulsading sphere on the contour lines...