simulated 3d print with geometry nodes
i want to simulate a 3d printed object with geometry nodes. Basic idea is to "slice" the object into different layers, get the bounding/surrounding edges and draw along them a profile.
First i get a vertical line, from center top to center bottom of the bounding box of the object.
Then i generate planes (grids to be truth) along the created line. the planes have the size of the x-y-bounding box of the object.
My logic tells me, when i intersect these planes with the original geometry with a boolean, i have to get slices of the object.
But intersecting gives me an empty result, while difference does the job... kind of... half of the mesh is missing.
Why does intersect not behaves like i thought?
Why is half the mesh missing?
thanks
Lks





...maybe a duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/279201/how-to-cut-a-mesh-into-a-flexible-number-of-pieces-along-a-certain-axis/

Thanks, with the link above I managed to build my own version. I left out the option to define the axis and resolution. But more or less the same.
Thank you.
